# Visual Studio 2022 dev tunnel on Blazor WASM hosted ASP.NET Core project

Tags: blazor, visual-studio-2022, dev-tunnels

I have a Blazor web assembly hosted in an ASP.NET Core 7 project.

I'm using Windows 10, and Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) - current version is 17.5.1.

I want to run it by Visual Studio 2022 on **dev tunnels** and view that site on my **mobile**.

I created tunnel but when I start the project by F5 in debug mode VS get error : **Unable to launch browser Could not open wss://**

My VS 2022 is logged in to my Microsoft account.

I have installed .NET 6.0 WebAssembly Build Tools and .NET WebAssembly Build Tools in my VS 2022.

How to run the Blazor project on a dev tunnel?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am facing a similar issue, except I need to get a webhook back from an external source...
If you can manage to do your mobile tests within your same lan, you could open the ports to your local machine on the lan?

Comment: @BrettJB Looks like an issue has been raised here:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Port-tunneling-doesnt-work-with-Blazor/10162604

Comment: I could run the project by running the NekoRay application and set a vless or trojan protocol and check the VPN Mode checkbox. But it can not show any thing on browsers on windows or android.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old issue but today it still persists, see [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Port-tunneling-doesnt-work-with-Blazor/10162604).
In the same thread, you see that it works without debugger.